# decimales antes y despues del punto - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

actualmente estoy intentando poner una tasa la cual varia según el tipo de moneda,
por ejemplo:
Si la moneda es USD entonces la tasa sera asi 1.000 (4 decimales despues del punto)
Si la moneda es HNL se hace una formula y el resultado me tiene que dar 2 decimales antes del punto y 4 despues del punto (Ejemplo: 24.1141)

Esta es la condicion que estoy usando

```
(CASE
             WHEN bp.Currency = 'USD' THEN '1.0000'
             ELSE
         (SELECT TOP 1
              er.BuyCash
          FROM dbo.ExchangeRates AS er
          WHERE CONVERT(DATE, er.ValidDate) = CONVERT(DATE, bp.ValueDate)
                AND er.BranchId = 0)
         END)
```

Sin embargo al ejecutar todo, cuando la moneda es USD me arroja una tasa de 1.00000, poniendo muchos ceros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Difícil de responder viendo solo ese trozo de código. Considera publicar un [mcve].

Comment: Por otro lado, veo que has escrito varias preguntas, para las que has recibido respuesta, y que [no has comentado, ni aceptado en ninguna de ellas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Si no sabes como realizar estas acciones, te invito a re-hacer el [tour].

Comment: Tu duda es como redondear un numero a 4 decimales, solo eso?

Comment: Si no comentas ni aceptas respuestas, la gente que voluntariamente está acá no se va a animar a responderte.

Comment: Hola, lo siento no sabia como aceptas las respuestas pero ya vi como, ahora me pondre al dia con ello, de antemano muchisimas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Las columnas solo pueden ser de un único tipo, es decir, no pueden tener dos configuraciones de decimales diferentes.
2. En el caso de tu consulta el motor resuelve el tipo de dato de la columna final de forma dinámica, eligiendo un configuración que sea consistente con todos los eventuales valores.
3. El que termina definiendo el tipo de dato (y los decimales) es la columna `BuyCash` que seguramente este definido como `NUMERIC(13,6)` o un valor similar. Finalmente el motor elige el tipo de dato más "inclusivo", en este caso el de mayor cantidad de decimales.

La solución es convertir el valor a un tipo que tenga los decimales deseados, pero recuerda que esto eventualmente estaría truncando información.

---

```
CONVERT(NUMERIC(13,4),
       (CASE WHEN bp.Currency = 'USD' THEN 1.0000
             ELSE (SELECT TOP 1
                      er.BuyCash
                      FROM dbo.ExchangeRates AS er
                      WHERE CONVERT(DATE, er.ValidDate) = CONVERT(DATE, bp.ValueDate)
                      AND er.BranchId = 0)
         END))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono perfecto